# Switch to skilled worker visa while on a funded PhD: impact on stipend and potential student fees repayment?

Tags: phd, funding, united-kingdom, visa

I'm currently doing a fully funded PhD in one of the UK universities, and I'm in my second year.

I have received a full-time job offer and want to switch to a skilled worker visa now. Does anyone know what will happen to my stipend and fees? Will the university stop paying my stipend? Should I pay the fees back?

Comment: It's a little unclear if you meant you will be dropping out of Ph.D to pursue a job, or continue as a part time student. I assume you are an International Student ? If so, first off check with your University's International Student Office on continuing to study with a work-visa, if there is any violation of immigration status. And then with your department on the stipend for newly adjusted hours.

Comment: @NebUzer *first off check with your University's International Student Office on continuing to study with a work-visa* there isn't

Comment: I'm not really sure how switching visa has any bearing on whether you owe back stipend or fees? But for clarity, in the UK I have never ever heard of a university requiring repayment of PhD 'fees' or stipend in the event of dropping out.